# Video editor that is free for commercial use

Tags: gratis, video-editing, windows-8

At company that I work I got a problem. I had to edit one video (that client sent me), but I can't find any editor that is free to use (in company) and have option to **crop** video (video have big black margins that I have to remove).

I want to produce MP4 file (H264) that can be embedded on on webpage (`<video>` tag), but I can convert it later.

Is there any piece of software that can I use to solve my problem? I'm running on Windows 8.1 (64-bit).

Comment: What kind of video file? And you should ask your superior: f a client sends you data that your company can't handle, what is the policy?

Comment: You didn't specify an OS – I assume it must run on Windows? What exact features are a must, and are there any that might be nice-to-have (but not crucially needed)? From the context, you probably mean "crop" (remove those margins) instead of "cut" (make the video shorter by removing scenes/frames)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [This Guide](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/21/how-to-crop-videos-with-free-software/), it shows how to crop a video in [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/), an open source video editor. Here's how it's done,

> ## Cropping Video
>
> Download the free Avidemux software from the project website [over at](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/download.html)
>   Sourceforge. The program is available for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.
>
> Install the software and load your video files via the file menu into
>   the application. You load the first file via File > Open, and
>   additional files via File > Append. You then have to replace the Copy
>   action under Video with another codec. I have selected MPEG-4 ASP
>   (Xvid) for instance.
>
> Click on the Filters button afterwards and selected Transform > Crop
>   from the selection.
>
> [image: crop videos]
>
> Click on the Configure button afterwards. This opens a preview image
>   of the video. Enter pixels in the left, right, top or bottom fields to
>   crop the video. The values are immediately shown on the preview image
>   so that it is easy to fine tune them. You can also try the auto crop
>   button which picked up the black bars in my test video nicely.
>
> [image: crop video]
>
> Click on the OK button to accept the changes. You can then click on
>   Preview in the previous configuration screen to see how the cropped
>   video will look like. If you are satisfied close the window.
>
> All you need to do know is to save the video via File > Save > Save
>   Video or with the Ctrl-S shortcut. The process may take some time
>   depending on the performance of your computer and the length of the
>   video.
>
> And that's all there is to it. This is without doubt one of the
>   easiest way to crop a video.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable on the command line, ffmpeg is a powerful tool that can do many different things, including crop.
https://ffmpeg.org

To crop using this tool you will craft a dos-shell command like:

```
ffmpeg -i sourcefile.mp4 -filter:v "crop=100:100:12:34" croppedFile.mp4
```

You have to spec the pixels manually using x-y coordinates, but your results will be precise and repeatable.
here is the help page on ffmpeg's crop tool:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop